# How to slide content opening up with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

My designer handed me a design I'm not 100% sure how to do with jquery and css.
I am basicly trying to allow a user to "slide" the footer up to reveal more conent.

My html..

```
 <div id="footer">
     <div id="expandingFooter"> hidden content</div>
        content that is always visible
 </div>
```

I have a toggle button that onclick

```
$('#expandingFooter').slideToggle();
```

This slides the expanding footer content open downward, then slides back up to close.
I would like it to slide up and then close down.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can leverage JQuery UI 1.6's Effects ([Effects Demo Page](http://ui.jquery.com/repository/real-world/effects/)).  The following accomplished the desired effect for me.

```
$('#toggleButton').bind('click', function(e) {
    $('#expandingFooter').toggle(
        'slide', 
        { easing: 'easeOutQuint', direction: 'down' }, 
        1000
    );
});
```

Note:  You may want to play with the easing parameter to get the desired smoothness of the effect.

You'll need to have the latest versions of both [JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) and [JQuery UI Slide Effect](http://ui.jquery.com/download_builder/) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shared-scripts/jquery-1.2.4b.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#footer").click(function () {
      if ($("#expandingFooter").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#expandingFooter").show("slow");
      } else {
        $("#expandingFooter").slideUp();
      }
    });
    $("#expandingFooter").hide();
  });
    //--></script>

</head>

<body>
 <div id="footer">
     <div id="expandingFooter"> hidden content</div>
        content that is always visible
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a bit of a trick. The slideUp() function the way you want is not build in JQuery because the way you can achieve it depends on your html/css design. Normal flow is from top to bottom.

I suggest this:

```
<a id="toggle">Toggle()</a>

<div id="slide" style="position:relative; height: 100px">

    <div id="slideInner" style="position:absolute; bottom: 0; background: lightblue"">
        <p>Suspendisse potenti. Vivamus libero. Dummy Text</p>
    </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.hoverable').hover( function() { $(this).find("div").show(); },
                       function() { $(this).find("div").hide(); } );

    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        $('#slideInner').slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

This code is just an example. Move the inline css to an external sheet. Idem for the javascript.

If you want the 'slide' div to disapeare, add a callback to the slideToggle() function a call hide() on the 'slide' div.